# Fastest and most efficient way to select and insert if not exist in one query in SQLite table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database table (sqlite). Let's say alarms and it has an only id(int) and name(text).

Here is the table structure:

[image]

All I want to do is do a select query but insert if the 'name' is not exist.
Something like this:

```
select name, (insert into alarms (name) values ('test_name')) from alarms where name = 'test_name'
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> 'new insert syntax error'

The important thing is that I want to do it all in one query.

Comment: Do you want to insert a record only if the name does not exist?

Comment: yes but also I want to get the name of that record also (select combination)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite, it's not possible to perform both, an insert and a select statement, in one (atomic) operation. So, I cannot give you a more satisfying answer.